# Could not find class 'com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo' in Android

Tags: android, junit

I created test Project. In that i created folder "robotium" and pasted 2 robotium jar files(robotium-solo-3.4.1-javadoc.jar and robtium-solo-3.4.1.jar).from the properties i configured java build path.But i got following failure  trace

```
      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo
      at com.example.pkg.test.ThisisitTest.setUp(ThisisitTest.java:19)
      at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
      at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
      at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
      at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

Comment: Some code would by handy

Comment: Is com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo an Activity?

Comment: Then, better post your answer and accept it. Or, remove this question. Otherwise, it will be listed in unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Debugable  to true in android manifest.

Comment: on the test project or the main project?

Answer (score 1):

`android:debuggable="true"` only doesn't solve the issue in my project. I've to add do this also.

"NoClassDefFoundError" is due to android sdk upgrade to version 17.
i need to check robotium.jar in "order and export" in my test project build path

Comment: @Fesstado As i have mentioned in my question, i have already set/configured that build path but even though i got that error.so i asked.

Comment: Ok, sorry. May be i've not ready your question correctly bevor